# Switching Injector alias from Mustache_Engine to Twig

Tags: php, frameworks, twig, composer-php, mustache

I am currently using [a tutorial to learn how to make a php project without a framework](https://github.com/PatrickLouys/no-framework-tutorial) so that I can understand frameworks a little more. I have worked on this and I am stuck at a point where I am going to switch an injector from Mustache_Engine to Twig

```
/**
 * Mustache Renderer
 */
/*$injector->alias('Todo\Template\Renderer', 'Todo\Template\MustacheRenderer');
$injector->define('Mustache_Engine', [
    ':options' => [
        'loader' => new Mustache_Loader_FilesystemLoader(dirname(__DIR__) . '/templates', [
            'extension' => '.html',
        ]),
    ],
]);*/

/**
 * Twig Environment
 */
$injector->alias('Todo\Template\Renderer', 'Todo\Template\TwigRenderer');
$injector->delegate('Twig_Environment', function () use ($injector) {
    $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(dirname(__DIR__) . '/templates');
    return new Twig_Environment($loader);
});
```

But all I get is the following error

> LogicException
>
> You must set a loader first.

I have no idea how to go about fixing this, but I have a feeling that I am doing something wrong here because many people have gone through this tutorial.

EDIT adding a screenshot for clarity

[image: screenshot of the error that I am getting]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this error in 2 different ways.

The first way, just replace `Twig_Environment` to `\Twig\Environment`, here full example code:

```
/**
 * Twig Environment
 */
$injector->alias('Todo\Template\Renderer', 'Todo\Template\TwigRenderer');
$injector->delegate('\Twig\Environment', function () use ($injector) {
    $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(dirname(__DIR__) . '/templates');
    return new Twig_Environment($loader);
});
```

The second way, add alias `$injector->alias(\Twig\Environment::class, 'Twig_Environment');`, here full example code:

```
/**
 * Twig Environment
 */
$injector->alias('Todo\Template\Renderer', 'Todo\Template\TwigRenderer');
$injector->delegate('Twig_Environment', function () use ($injector) {
    $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(dirname(__DIR__) . '/templates');
    return new Twig_Environment($loader);
});
$injector->alias(\Twig\Environment::class, 'Twig_Environment');
```

More information about this error you can find here: https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/2907

In a nutshell about the error: from version 1.38.0 Twig package use namespace classes as the default classes (PSR-0 ones are aliases). More details you can find here https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/pull/2862 and also in changelog https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/3.x/CHANGELOG#L447